# Worst case scenario in 2048

Tags: optimization, game, 2048-game

The game 2048 can be thought as a two player game, where one player shifts the table around to get to the 2048 tile, while the other player tries to hinder them by putting down 2s and 4s on the table. While the [original game](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) will put down the tiles randomly [there](http://sztupy.github.io/2048-Hard/) [are](http://aj-r.github.io/Evil-2048/) variants, such as some where this is not random, and also [some](http://lymia.github.io/Anti-2048/) where you are the one putting down the tiles, and the computer will shift the table around (not to mention the [general](http://akhilanb.github.io/Human2048/) one, where you can play both sides).

Theoretically, the worst situation is the following table, but for this the player shifting the table has to play really badly.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 2 |

If however both players play flawlessly against each other, then what is the highest tile that the shifting player can achieve?

Comment: Hard to define "perfect" here...

Comment: @BlueFlame I don't think it's really ambiguous; ideal strategy, like any other game.

Comment: How many 2s and 4s are allowed to be put in a turn? Your last link allows the table to be filled as per your worst case example.

Comment: @SQB: only one per turn. The last example is just a sandbox

Comment: I'm just trying to get through 2021, we're worrying about 2048 already?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When playing [deterministic 2048](http://jmfork.github.io/2048/), where a new tile is placed in the first available spot, you can get a pattern like this using left-down-left-down:

[image: det 2048]

The worst I have been able to get in regular 2048 is this:

[image: reg 2048]

It *is* possible to get that worst-case scenario if your tile generator and human are working together to do so.

Comment: That a really large images :O

Comment: Sorry. I took them on a netbook, so i was expecting them to be smaller.

Comment: I know this is old, but you can add "m" before the file extension in the Imgur link to use the mobile version of the image, which is smaller